# Android RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.squareup.picasso.PicassoProvider

Tags: android, picasso

I am getting PicassoProvider crash on App launch. This started happening when I moved one library ('com.github.loopsocial:firework_sdk:5.3.8') to the dynamic module. Earlier this dependency was in app module. When the dependency was in app module then no such crash was coming.

Any solution for this crash?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.squareup.picasso.PicassoProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.squareup.picasso.PicassoProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.abc-7SimyXXbKeA9ZazLIuesbw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.abc-7SimyXXbKeA9ZazLIuesbw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.abc-7SimyXXbKeA9ZazLIuesbw==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.abc-7SimyXXbKeA9ZazLIuesbw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.abc-7SimyXXbKeA9ZazLIuesbw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.abc-7SimyXXbKeA9ZazLIuesbw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.abc-7SimyXXbKeA9ZazLIuesbw==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6672)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6567)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1887)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Comment: Can you please post your app level `build.gradle` ?

Answer (score -2):

PicassoProvider has been removed in favor of creating and managing your own Picasso instances using manual or framework-based DI.

For this we have to create own Picasso object and pass it where its needed.

And one more solutions add build gradle java version

```
android {
....
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}
```

more details refer [PicassoProvider issue](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/2121)